# Problem with "Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface"

Tags: 10.10, kernel, wireless, drivers

I just did fresh install from Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop CD and I can't use my wiresless card.

```
 sylwia@mutalisk:~$ lspci
 (...)
 00:0b.0 Network controller: Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface
 (...)
```

When I try modprobe acx I get `FATAL: Module acx not found`.

Output of: `lspci -nnvv | grep Network\ controller`:

```
 00:0b.0 Network controller [0280]: Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface [104c:8400]
```

Comment: Could you update the question with your PCI IDs for this device.  Please include the output of this command: lspci -nnvv | grep Network\ controller

Comment: This question is abandoned - if you feel this is in error, then please flag explaining why and the moderators will re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't ship a driver for that hardware because it [isn't supported in the upstream wireless tree](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/acx1xx) (not to mention its questionable legal status).  On the other hand, Debian ships a compilable source called `acx100-source`, and you can find instructions for using it [here](http://wiki.debian.org/acx).